# Cakephp3 rest parameter/filter

Tags: php, api, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I  use CakePHP 3 and try to create a REST access.

When connecting to homepage.tld/invoices.json I get all invoices (which is correct).

But now I'd like to use parameter/filter to reduce the output and fetch specific invoices:

> homepage.tld/invoices.json?id=5 <-- only the invoice with id 5
>
> homepage.tld/invoices.json?customer_id=3 <-- all invoices with a
> customer_id=3

Is there a simple solution or is manual programming required?

Comment: `is manual programming required` Recognise that CakePHP is a framework (it is a tool for you to write code with/around) - not a cms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple solution or is manual programming required?

Yes, *you* need to write code for that.

But you can use the [friends of cake search plugin](https://github.com/friendsofcake/search) for that, it will make it easy and less repetitive.